# Are there any more Elminster novels coming?

Tags: forgotten-realms

Elminster is one of the best written characters in the Forgotten Realms after Drizzt (IMO). so what I would like to know is are we going to see any more works with Elminster penned by his creator Ed Greenwood or any other author currently writing for Forgotten Realms?

Comment: Agreed entirely.  Let me see if I can coax this info out of the web. You did read The Herald, right?

Comment: I need to know what your last book was.  The various wikis of the world haven't been updated in regards to Greenwood's books, and his last one was just 11 months ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update (2019) - it would appear that there are no more Eliminster-focused novels forthcoming.

> **Q:** *After Death Masks, Are there any more Elminster-related stories coming?*
>
> **[Ed Greenwood](https://mobile.twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1152900224857362432)**: *Book length? Don't know. I've already penned a few Mirt tales that have Elminster briefly appearing as a supporting character (they were up at DM's Guild and will be again). If any publishers out there want to do a licensing deal with Wizards for Elminster novels, I'm game!.*

---

I asked my good friend Ed Greenwood what his plans were regarding Elminster. You'll be pleased to hear that you won't have to wait long for a [new story](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/fiction/novels-ebooks/death-masks) with your fave character.

> **Q:** *Are there any more Elminster-related stories coming?*
>
> **[Ed Greenwood](https://twitter.com/TheEdVerse/status/736306952167260161?lang=en)**: *Oh, yes. Early June: DEATH MASKS, new Realms novel in hc from Wizards of the Coast, by yours truly, has old El in it!*

Comment: Being Supreme Chancellor sure gives you a lot of connections.

Comment: @armadillo  - You just have to ask nicely